# Ubuntu 22.04 keeps logging me out of my google accounts

Tags: browser

I recently downloaded ubuntu 22.04, and whenever I log in into my google accounts on any browser, it stays for a while, then either mid session it logs me out, or after i close the browser.

All my other accounts other than google stay logged in, i made sure all the browsers don't delete cookies, and that they save data.

I've tried Google Chrome, Firefox, and Brave all had the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried logging into your Google account via Chrome instead of Google?

Comment: i did on both, same result each time.
It pauses my sync and asks for login each time

Comment: Does this help? https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=152657

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix This question is about the unwanted browser logout, not any unwanted desktop logout. Though now with that idea I do suspect keyring problems if there was a lockscreen anytime in between

Comment: it doesn't have to be a lock screen, i had it log out on me multiple times mid session, i'd open a new tab and it would ask me to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution for Google Chrome:

Open Chrome then click on triple dot on top right ⇾ Settings ⇾ Privacy and security ⇾ Site Settings ⇾ Additional Content settings ⇾ On device site data ⇾> then finally select "Allow sites to save data on your device"

For everything that remains, maybe you should recreate your Google account in Ubuntu settings. Go to Settings ⇾ Online accounts ⇾ Google - delete it then set up once again.